# Whats the best way to concat Strings in java? As Java code is run on JVM and not on OS itself, why is there a huge difference in performance?

Tags: java, jvm

I was trying to figure out best way to concatenate Strings in java. So I tested three approaches and was surprised by the results. These are the three approaches

```
private static String test1(String delimiter, String... data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : data) {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(delimiter);
    }
    return sb.replace(sb.length() - delimiter.length(), sb.length(), "").toString();
}

private static String test2(String delimiter, String... data) {
    String join = "";
    for(String s : data)
        join += s + delimiter;
    return join.substring(0, join.length() - delimiter.length());
}

private static String test3(String delimiter, String... data) {
    return String.join(delimiter, data);
}
```

tested this input with and "," as delimiter:

```
String[] data = new String[100000];
Arrays.fill(data, "*");
```

Test bench: Core i5 2.2ghz, 8gb ram, 256gb ssd, Windows 7
Results averaging around:

1. test1 -> 10ms
2. test2 -> 18038ms
3. test3 -> 17341ms

test2 result is obvious, but test3 should have performed nearly as good as test1 as it is roughly the same code underneath. So I tested with another bench and was surprised again.

Test bench2: Core i5 1.6ghz, 4gb ram, 128gb ssd, OSX El-Capitan

Results averaging around:

1. test1 -> 9ms
2. test2 -> 7171ms
3. test3 -> 9ms

What is the reason for this strange behavior? 
And why is it that lower specs of bench2 performing better(In case of test2)?

---

My question is not about StringBuilder vs String concat. It's why is there a huge difference in running times of same code on different OSes? String.join(....) is taking as much time as String concat on windows and StringBuilder on OSX

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] data = new String[100000];
    Arrays.fill(data, "*");

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    test1(",", data);
    System.out.println("test1->" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + "ms");

    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    test2(",", data);
    System.out.println("test2->" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + "ms");

    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    test3(",", data);
    System.out.println("test3->" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + "ms");
}

private static String test1(String delimiter, String... data) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : data) {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append(delimiter);
    }
    return sb.replace(sb.length() - delimiter.length(), sb.length(), "").toString();
}

private static String test2(String delimiter, String... data) {
    String join = "";
    for(String s : data)
        join += s + delimiter;
    return join.substring(0, join.length() - delimiter.length());
}

private static String test3(String delimiter, String... data) {
    return String.join(delimiter, data);
}
```

Comment: Because you're allocating too many string instances.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the OS is not irrelevant. The JVM reads the bytecode, but in the end it is still the kernel that does the real computation.

Comment: @Gendarme - I'm not sure it's the *OS* that's doing the computation...

Comment: How are you doing benchmarking?  Doing _any_ kind of measurement of Java performance is _really, really hard._

Comment: @SLaks how does too many instances effect performance on two different OSes. If that's the reason then both should perform poorly right?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I did it using System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: @KrishnaSaiU then your measurements are almost certainly badly misleading.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what's the appropriate way to do it? And why is it misleading?

Comment: The only realistically reliable way to do benchmarking like this in Java is to use a tool like JMH, that can account properly for the JIT, for garbage collection and allocation, warming up your code, etc.

Comment: @KrishnaSaiU please, PLEASE read more about Java benchmarking. This is pretty elementary, and almost certainly is due to warming up + JIT issue that Louis W pointed out. All you are measuring between OSes/platforms are differences between those aspects.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: @StaxMan Thanks a lot for the information.